# "standard co-deviation"

Tags: probability, statistics, notation, terminology

This is a terminology/notation question.  I swear I've seen covariance matrices written as

\begin{bmatrix}
  \sigma_x^2 & \sigma_{x,y}^2 \\
  \sigma_{y,x}^2 & \sigma_y^2
\end{bmatrix}

Given that $\sigma_x^2$ is a variance, then $\sigma_x$ is a standard deviation.

**Given that $\sigma_{x,y}^2$ is a covariance, what is $\sigma_{x,y}$ called?**  Does it have a name?

Comment: I don't think $\sigma^2_{x,y}$ is good notation, since the covariances can be negative. Thinking of the "co-standard deviations" as being imaginary isn't very helpful either.

Comment: @Ian : That's what I would have said if you hadn't said it first. Maybe you could make your comment into an answer.

Comment: That's a good point.  I was only thinking about the symbols, not what they mean.  But is an imaginary $\sigma_{x,y}$ really so un-informative?  I'm having a hard time picturing it, but wouldn't it represent a scaling and rotation?  (Just thinking aloud)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think $σ^2_{x,y}$ is good notation, since the covariances can be negative. Thinking of the "co-standard deviations" as being imaginary isn't very helpful either, because the covariance matrix is symmetric, so its eigenvalues are real. So in some sense everything that can be said about covariance "lives in the real numbers".